# Link to frame labels

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a mainMovie clip that consist of different movie clips. Inside of my mainMovi I have another movie clip that is called "Menus" this where all my navigation is but the frame labels are inside the mainMovie.

**Here is my code:**

```
on (release) {
    _level1.gotoAndPlay("nordic");
}
```

**i also have tried:**

```
on (release) {
    _root.gotoAndPlay("nordic");
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
on (release) {
    _root.web1.gotoAndPlay("nordic");
}
```

I have to declare the root gave the main movie clip a instance name and voila!